# Checkout page takes 7 or more seconds to place order

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-methods, pagespeed, speedoptimization

[image]

***My checkout page is taking 7 or more seconds every time to place order***.

Can anybody let me know what could be the possible reason or how can I debug this issue?

I am totally confused from where should I start.

***It is happing with every payment method.***

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try doing profiling and see what takes time. It's hard to say without looking inside

Comment: I enabled profiler, but I am not able to understand 1 thing after clicking place order, payment information takes time so the 7s timer will it be mentioned or not in the list of profiler

Answer (score 0):

This can be due to multiple reason and can impact cumulatively.
Analyses below stated and points and act on each.
Important one as per your screen posted.

```
1. Low quality of hosting, VPS:

2. Run in Production mode.

3. Check JS overall required on checkout,lower the JS size better it will be.

4. Turn on cache( I expect this is in place).

5. Analyses modules installed that are impacting/extending your checkout.


6. HTTP 2 and no JS merge.
```

**Other points to be looked at**

```
7. How far is the payment gateway server from your hosting location.Should be in same country.

8. Upgrade Magento version to 2.3.x.

9. Clean data base for old quotes and logged data that are not of much use.
```

**Questions**: are you using Magento default checkout or have you installed some checkout module.

Comment: I have installed one step checkout, but even when I disable it by default magento2 checkout is taking time. The screenshot added is of default magento2 checkout

Comment: Please follow the above steps, you can get it faster or less time consume.